# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::createuser(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I used hyn/tenancy https://tenancy.dev/docs/hyn/5.4 and created an application like this: https://www.seismicpixels.com/creating-a-laravel-saas-framework-part-6/

At the moment I'm having the problem that I'm trying to setup a registration controller for users within the tenant. I tried doing this with a second public function in the registration controller

```
protected function createuser(array $data)
    {
        print_r($data);
        die();
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

The showRegistrationForm() function is:

```
/**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.registeruser');
    }
```

The error I'm facing is (as far as i do understand), says that there's no array, which could be selected as $data . I tried using the die() like above but `array $data` isn't going through.

I also tried using the standard registration page which is

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('register.users') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Register
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and here's my web.php where the registration routes are shown, but I don't think the problem is within here because i'm getting an error out of the function, so the routing works?

```
 // Register Routes
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterUserController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register.user');
    Route::post('registeruser', 'Auth\RegisterController@createuser')->name('register.users');
```

I hope somebody can help me with this error (probably on my side )
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
protected function createuser(Request $request)
    {
        print_r($request->name);
        die();
        return User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);
    }
```

You are passing the `$data` as parameter but not definig it in you route:
try this hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Your `registers.users` should use `Auth\RegisterController@register` method. `createuser` is called inline and receives `$request->all()`
Btw, default name for the function is `create()`, no `createuser` (if you don't want to modify `register` method)